# Preserving comments in create-react-app (react-scripts v4)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

Is there any way to keep some comments in the source code for create-react-app (react-scripts v4.0.3 at the time of writing this)? I'm trying to get a comment like this to be preserved in a production build:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) blah blah blah
 * Written by Blah blah
 */
```

I see this GitHub issue about this very problem: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4596

And supposedly it was fixed by this PR: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4601#issuecomment-424589230

But according to this comment Terser is used instead of Uglify https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4601#issuecomment-424589230

I see that several license comments are preserved in the production build that are in `node_modules`, and I suppose I could have a module just for the sake of including license info, but I'd really like to preserve comments in the source code if possible.

Comment: CRA doesn't expose any way to override the Terser configuration, which you can see here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/b45ae3c9caf10174d53ced1cad01a272d164f8de/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L237-L275.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, bummer, sounds like a "no" then. I was hoping there was an env var like "PRESERVE_LICENSE" or something.  I'm puzzled how the node_modules licenses are being preserved by create-react-app.  I guess I can dig in the src some more and see.  Thanks for the info.